# IPTV broadcast through the internet

Tags: networking, vlc-media-player, iptv

it happened to me that I have to leave but I have an IPTV at my home computer I would like to be able to watch it while I'm gone.

- IPTV comes with the Lan cable, but I can't access internet with it, though I can watch all of the channels through the VLC.
- It also happens that i have a fixed external ip behind the router so I can forward all the ports to my main linux computer, setup ssh or http servers if needed.

I'm not a pro of networking and I need to know, whether it is possible to watch IPTV through the internet by connecting to my home pc via that fixed ip adress? Of course you can do it by using remote desktop, but I think everyone will agree that this is not an option.

As a solution I thought of something like on this chart, including buying another LAN card and making both networks work at the same time. One for the internet and one for the IPTV. It's only my idea though, it may be impossible, so I'm asking maybe there are any hotshots who could suggest something to me.

Edit: I would like to turn my home pc into broadcasting device. While it also would allow to connect to it through the ssh.

[image]

Comment: I don't have any TV. And all ports are already in use on my router..

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is setup your router to allow the IPTV device to be viewed from the internet

This link should help you set up your router:
http://www.my-iptv.com/us/eng/faq_12.php

Since there are so many routers, you will need to know how to log in to the router, and how to setup forwarding.  Not knowing your router, I can not tell you that part, but this is the general solution.

Comment: Is there any way to convert my home pc to IPTV device? Which would broadcast television over the internet?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: I don't think that any device needed. I think that there's a need of proper vpn configuration (or something like this) to use the network card of my home computer, then i could watch the IPTV through the VLC with the same UDP adresses? Can it be that easy?